# How to retrieve the content of a dynamically generated TextBox in a GridView cell in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have a `GridView` with the rows represents students and columns for their marks in different subjects. The number of students is variable. Thus, the number of rows in the `GridView` is unknown. Users when entering the marks will specify the number of students in runtime. Each row has a TextBox for each subject.

After the user click on calculate button I need to retrieve the values in all the `TextBoxes`.

I tried the following code:

```
protected void GridView2_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)

    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            List<TextBox> list = new List<TextBox>(); 
            if (ViewState["Table"] != null)
                Assessments = (DataTable)ViewState["Table"]; 
            int count = 1;
            foreach (DataRow row in Assessments.Rows)
            {
                TextBox txt = new TextBox();
                txt.ID = "AsTxt"; 
                txt.Text = string.Empty;
                txt.TextChanged += OnTextChanged; 
                e.Row.Cells[count].Controls.Add(txt);
                count += 2;
                listd.Add((e.Row.DataItem as DataRowView).Row[0].ToString() + "Txt");
            }
        }
    }
```

And for the calculation button:

```
protected void CalculateBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            GridViewRow rr = GridView2.Rows[0];
            TextBox rrrr = (rr.FindControl("AsTxt") as TextBox); 
            ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "alert", "alert('" + rrrr.Text + "')", true);
        }
```

The code didn't work as it always returns NullReferenceException, that is rrrr is null.

Can anybody help me with this?

Comment: I think in one row there are several `AsTxt`.

Comment: @aria no, even when I removed the foreach block the problem persists.

Comment: Make sure row 0 have `AsTxt` and do something like this `TextBox box1 = (TextBox)Gridview1.Rows[0].Cells[1].FindControl("AsTxt");`

Comment: @aria the same problem, I'm sure the location of the TextBox is in Row[0].Cells[1].

Comment: Did you test that to find it in Cell 1 ?

Comment: @aria yes i did. i'm sure.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't Find Controls in GridView on Dynamic Controls](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33737710/cant-find-controls-in-gridview-on-dynamic-controls)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to access the textbox as per cell no in the row

```
protected void CalculateBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            GridViewRow rr = GridView2.Rows[0];

            TextBox rrrr = (rr.Cells[0].FindControl("AsTxt") as TextBox); 
            ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "alert", "alert('" + rrrr.Text + "')", true);
        }
```

Currently I have put 0 as in the cell index, change it as per your gridview row.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can add the data on page load so that asp.net will persist the viewstate automatically. So your controls will be present. Always you need to add the controls in page load values changed by you will be tracked by asp.net automatically.

Comment: can you please tell me how to add the data on page load? where is page load? and what code should I put there?

Comment: asp.net has pag_load event. Same code you can put into method and call that method in page load

Comment: which code? the code in 'GridView2_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)' or the code in 'CalculateBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)'

Comment: also I don't want the GridView to generate TextBox always only and rowdatabound event occur. I think if I put the code in the function rowdatabound in the page_load this will always generate the TextBox.